# Missing } in template expression

Tags: javascript

Code is simple and quite right. It runs fine in console but not in editor. What is the reason for this? Is it because fiddle is not responding well or something else.

```
let x = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  x += i; 
  console.log(  ` number is :  ${x}` );
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxye24mp/18/

Comment: `console.log(\`${x}\`)`... why? Why not just `console.log(x)`? Am I missing something?

Comment: (  ` number is :  ${x}` )

Comment: It works if I change it from TypeScript to JavaScript

Comment: It also works in the TypeScript Playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYewTgBAFANgpgFwgSwgXggBgNwogHggGZdkBqMgSggG8AoCPMjZXBiAYxADsBnEeADoYIAOZQIAAwAkNZAF9JEStjrzsQA). Must be a JSFiddle issue. Please post it as a bug on the JSFiddle GitHub repo. Also, post the error in the question itself from next time.

Comment: Thanks! You are right Its a bug there maybe..

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Yes, this is a huge issue, I went to the official string template example from jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alajfit/ybvjLtgd/), and modified the language to TypeScript [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bky1zxd9/) and it has the same error

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I notice with your jsfiddle, you are using TypeScript, not normal JavaScript. I personally don't know why this is causing the error, but it is.

Comment: Yes. All JavaScript code will run in TypeScript, or at least it's supposed to.